# I'm fetching with find and i need to get latest published article in conjunction with limit in Strapi

Tags: strapi

```
const { data } = await this.$axios.get(`/articles?_sort=published:ASC&_limit=9`)
```

Is there a way to actually sort on date or do I need to write my own custom route? 
If am to build my custom route, what kind of query should I be using?

Answer (score 1):

```
const { data } = await this.$axios.get(`/articles?_sort=published:desc&_limit=9`)
```

You were sorting by asc not desc